# The same name macro with different arguments

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros

Is it possible to have 2 macros with the same name, but different arguments? Something like this:

```
#define FI(value) do {l<<value;  Doit(l); } while(0)
#define FI(value, level) do {l<<value ; Doit(l,level); } while(0)
```

Comment: Yes, it's called "Inline functions".

Comment: @DeadMG Some people don't like to hear it, but there are cases where we need macros. Like syntactic sugar for loops. See [BOOST_FOREACH](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/foreach.html). Of course, your argument is very good for this example here.

Comment: @leemes C++11's range-based for-loop supersedes `BOOST_FOREACH` :)

Comment: @FredOverflow I know. But (1) there are still cases in which custom loops are nice, (2) there are compilers out there which don't yet fully support C++11. I think there are some libraries we want to still support older compilers, even in the next couple of years. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not possible.
A symbol name cannot be redefined. Unlike functions macros cannot be overloaded. Think of it logically macros are for pure textual replacement, So how can you replace two different things for the same entity?

**An alternative and better solution:**
You can write a *[inline function](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/inline-functions.html)* for achieving the same result. It provides you additional advantage of *type* checking and saves you from the murky side effects of macros.

Comment: One definition rule has nothing to do with preprocessor macros. And you can redefine macro provided you used #undef before.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec: You are correct. Macros are evaluated at preprocessing and the compiler, which implements ODR never sees any macro.

Answer (score 6):

This would work.

```
#define FI(value, ...) FI_(value, ##__VA_ARGS__, 2, 1)
#define FI_(value, level, n, ...) FI##n(value, level)
#define FI1(value, ...) do {l << value; Doit(l);} while (0)
#define FI2(value, level) do {l << value; Doit(l, level);} while (0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is possible. However, it will result in *compiler warning* regarding redefinition.

See this for more details:
http://efesx.com/2010/08/31/overloading-macros/

Comment: Dead link - it doesn't look like it is possible. Trying it myself in Visual Studio yields an error about redefinition.

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation in which you really should use inline functions. Knowing nothing about the types you are using, a possible implementation might look like this:

```
template<typename T>
inline void fi(T & l, const T & value) {
   l << value;
   Doit(l);
}

template<typename T>
inline void fi(T & l, const T & value, const T & level) {
   l << value;
   Doit(l, level);
}
```

If you ever encounter a situation in which you have to stick to macros, you will have to work-around this limitation that they can't be overloaded, at least not per the standard. To "overload" them, we just write the number of arguments on the name of the macro, which is a common way to do so (in fact, even the OpenGL library uses this method to "overload" C functions).

```
#define FI1(value) do {l<<value;  Doit(l); } while(0)
#define FI2(value, level) do {l<<value ; Doit(l,level); } while(0)
```

Comment: Can't use `##` for variable name concatenation.